# How to change the text of the label box dynamically in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jakarta-ee, dom-events

In my jsp page, I have one button and one label. When page loading, the text of the label box is "Test". Suppose, user clicks the button then I have to change the text of the label into "tested".

I am new to Jsp.So, Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first need to set a listener to your button, say our markup was as follows:

```
<button id='btn'>test it</button>
<span id='label'>Test</span>
```

We can select the button element, and set it's onclick attribute:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = test
```

Then we can define a function call `test` that will toggle the label:

```
function test(){
 document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = 'Tested';
}
```

And that's it!

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNcNy/) demonstrating this code.

Comment: A little JavaScript goes a long way..,

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
    document.getElementById("atext").innerHTML="tested";
}
</script>

<label id="atext">test</label>
<input type="button" onClick="fnc()" value="click me">
```